# How to apply a custom MessageBodyWriter to lists of objects?

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

In a Dropwizard web service I want to return objects of class `Test` in a database using following custom `MessageBodyWriter`.

```
 @Provider
 @Produces("application/Test")
 public class TestMarshaller implements MessageBodyWriter<Test>{
     public long getSize(Test obj, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
         return -1;
     }
     public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
         return type == Test.class;
     }
     public void writeTo(Test obj, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
        str.append(obj.getData());
        outputStream.write(str.toString().getBytes());  
     }
}
```

This works fine for single objects with the following method

```
@GET
@Produces("application/Test")
@Path("/{ID}")
public Test getTest(@PathParam(value = "ID") LongParam ID) {
    Test result = Test.findInDB(ID.get());
    return result;
}
```

Now I want to use the same `MessageBodyWriter` for a list of elements.

```
@GET
@Produces("application/Test")
@Path("/{ID}")
public List<Test> getTest(@PathParam(value = "ID") String IDs) {
    List<Test> listTest = Test.findMultiInDB(IDs);
    return listTest;        
}
```

That resulted in the error

> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/Test, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List.

A [search](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jax_rs_returning_a_list) suggested the usage of `GenericEntity`.

```
@GET
@Produces("application/Test")
@Path("/{ID}")
public Response getTest(@PathParam(value = "ID") String IDs) {
    List<Test> listTest = Test.findMultiInDB(IDs);
    GenericEntity<List<Test>> result = new GenericEntity<List<Test>>(listTest) {};
    return Response.ok(result).build(); 
}
```

Unfortunately it resulted in the exact same error as above.
My question is what do I need to change to make it work or is another `MessageBodyWriter` necessary that deals with the lists?

Comment: can you try with `Object` as a type parameter of `MessageBodyWriter` instead of `Test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear, Jersey looks for a `MessageBodyWriter` with type `java.util.List`, but finds only `MessageBodyWriter<Test>`, so either create a new one for List `MessageBodyWriter<java.util.List>` or use `Object` and use if else on Object class.

Comment: Using a writer for `List<Test>` seems to be the more sensible approach. Thank you.